# Best practices for class/subclass composite of another class/subclass respectively in JAVA (android) which involve list<class/subclass> return methods

Tags: java, list, inheritance, subclass, covariance

For example, suppose I have a class

```
class Engine {
    int horsepower;
    ...
}
```

and subclass

```
class EngineTurbo extends Engine {
    Some turbineProperty;
    ...
}
```

on the other hand, I have a class (with some List return method)

```
class Plane {
    Engine[] planeEngines;
    ...

    public List<Engine> getListOfEngines() { ... }
}
```

and here is my question, having this subclass:

```
class PlaneTurbo extends Plane {
    EngineTurbo[] planeEngines;    // yes or no?
    ...

    public PlaneTurbo(int quantity){
        planeEngines = new EngineTurbo[quantity];    // yes? or...
        super.planeEngines = new EngineTurbo[quantity];
    }

    public List<EngineTurbo> getListOfEngines() { ... }    // best practices here
}
```

I'd like to know about best practices on the return List < SubClass >  case. 
I found some answers about using List < ? extends Engine > and something like that

Also found this terrific [help (I share with all of you)](https://briangordon.github.io/2014/09/covariance-and-contravariance.html) but still I'm looking for best solution for this case

Thanks

Ah, BTW, after all of this I have another class (not subclass, or maybe yes), like...

```
class HangarOnlyTurboPlanes {
    List<PlaneTurbo> turboPlanes;    // only PlaneTurbo, not need Plane
    ... 
    public void someLogicInvolvingOnlyTurboPlanes(){
        List<EngineTurbo> engines = turboPlanes.get(some).getListOfEngines();
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are asking why, I'm working with "TURBO" app, but I like to keep it open to future another upperClass apps (maybe just Hangar) and/or siblingClass app (maybe SpaceEngineHangar whatever)

Thanks again

Comment: It will be good to add a new tag " best-practices " maybe :)

Comment: There is no 'best-practices' tag because questions asking for best practices are off-topic, as they are opinion-based. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/1364007).

Comment: I am not sure that there is a good answer to your question.  One can speak definitively or authoritatively about solutions for a use case with a particular problem domain.  Here, all one can do is answer speculatively or generally about a solution that is looking for a problem.

Comment: @WaiHaLee The answer given was perfect, and I believe is a closed question. But, should I rewrite question anyway? Or let it as answered like this? BTW, now I understand about this forum's rules about opinion-based questions, and next time I will be more specific (good links, I liked yannis answer)

Comment: @scottb you're right. I was looking for just one posible good solution to this. But because your comment I'm thinking about, are there another ways to resolve this? not like "generics" as tsolakp's good answer... I'm just curious, you don't need to answer that I already resolved it, but I'm just thinking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a candidate for generics. Where Plane will have reference not to concrete `Engine` but to a generics subclass of `Engine` that are specified by sub classes of `Plane`.

Change your `Plane` to be generic:

```
public class Plane<E extends Engine> {
    E[] planeEngines;

    public List<E> getListOfEngines() {return Arrays.asList(planeEngines);}
}
```

Then in your subclass all you have to do is specify concrete type of `Engine` and dont need to define a new variable to just hold `EngineTurbo` list:

```
public class PlaneTurbo extends Plane<EngineTurbo> {
    public PlaneTurbo(int quantity) {
        planeEngines = new EngineTurbo[quantity];
    }
}
```

And finally your can get your `EngineTurbo` from `PlaneTurbo` without the need to define a new method that only returns `EngineTurbo` or some type of cast:

```
PlaneTurbo pt = new PlaneTurbo(5);        
List<EngineTurbo> ets = pt.getListOfEngines();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is the solution I was looking for, I tried it and it works perfect